# Chrome page does not finish loading

Tags: google-chrome

I have a simple web page running locally on my machine using XAMPP.

When in Chrome and I load the page, the page appears to load fine and appears as expected. The icon in the tab continues to show the spinning "loading" icon though, it never stops.

Using Chrome Developer tools I can see the network tab and there is nothing showing as loading
Also if I use Internet Explorer then the page loads and there is no loading icon.

Any idea why Chrome might think it is still loading something?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how your question is related directly to programming: what part of your web page is not completing its download, and what is the corresponding code?

Comment: It's related to programming because I am writing the code behind the web page and getting results I cant explain. I don't know which part is not completing its download, that's the point of the question, how do I find out?

Comment: I could post the HTML for the page but its about 400 lines and not sure it would be legible on here

Comment: If you systematically cut out some elements of the page, you should be able to narrow down what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found out it was one of my chrome extensions. I tried loading my site in an incognito page and the loading symbol stopped after the page finished. I went through my extensions to see which were not allowed in incognito and eventually found that it was "Mailto: for Gmail™ 2.4" causing the problem.

Comment: for me it was fb pixel extension

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth after eight years, I had a similar problem where Chrome would not load some images even though they were definitely available, ready, and waiting.

My solution was to close the browser, flushing cookies, history, and all the other internal cruft which had built up over time (using the "Close All & Clean" extension).

Restarting the browser and reloading the page, everything was there, all tickety-boo.

I have no useful theories on why this might've worked but as they say "works for me."  Your mileage may vary.